# Accessing result of another Thread that's running a loop

Tags: java, multithreading

`Thread A` is a loop that performs calculations.

`Thread B` needs to read result produced by each iteration of loop enclosed in `Thread A`.

What would be the best approach to achieve this without blocking anything?

Comment: Can Thread B block while waiting for Thread A to produce another calculation? Also, are you open to using java libraries like RxJava?

Comment: Thread B can wait while Thread A completes each iteration. I would prefer sticking to built-in libraries unless it would make the code much more readable. Performance is key since application operates in real/near-real time.

Comment: Just start a new thread for each update. Use `ExecutorService`

Comment: Hint: you are "over-tagging". This is a simple java multi-threading question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need the Producer-Consumer pattern here. In Java, you can use `BlockingQueue`s to implement it. Here's an example with an `ArrayBlockingQueue` that is used to deliver `Double` calculation results from a producer to a consumer:

**Producer.java**

```
class Producer implements Runnable {
    private final BlockingQueue<Double> queue;

    public Producer(BlockingQueue<Double> q) {
        queue = q;
    }

    public void run() {
        try {
            while (true) {
                Double result = calculateResult();
                // This call will make the result available to the consumer:
                queue.put(result);
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            // Handle thread interruption here
        }
    }
}
```

**Consumer.java**

```
class Consumer implements Runnable {
    private final BlockingQueue<Double> queue;

    public Consumer(BlockingQueue<Double> q) {
        queue = q;
    }

    public void run() {
        try {
            while (true) {
                // This call Will wait until the next result is available:
                Double result = queue.take();
                // Process the result...
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            // Handle thread interruption here
        }
    }
}
```

**Program.java**

```
class Program {
    public static void main() {
        BlockingQueue<Double> queue = new ArrayBlockingQueue<>();
        Producer producer = new Producer(queue);
        Consumer consumer = new Consumer(queue);
        new Thread(producer).start();
        new Thread(consumer).start();
    }
}
```

If you need, you can create several consumers or several producers (or both) that share the same queue. That will allow you to balance the work between more than two threads.

Also have a look at the `BlockingQueue`'s capabilities and on other implementations, there're plenty of them.

Comment: If I would be to add a third Thread C that would take in result off Thread B then handling such chain of multiple layers of BlockingQueues be still feasible or would there be better approaches?

Comment: Such pipelining would work perfectly, it's a common architectural pattern. A consumer of one queue (Thread B) can also play role of a supplier to another queue (Thread C): Thread A -> Queue1 -> Thread B -> Queue 2 -> Thread C.